# Zend_Validate_InArray with array of pattern

Tags: php, regex, validation, zend-framework, zend-form

I wrote a validate regex in a Zend form:

```
$card = new Zend_Validate_Regex(
        array('pattern' => '/1234*/',)
    );
$card->setMessage($this->getView()->translate('ERROR_CARD_FORMAT'));
```

I need to add different patterns:

```
$card = new Zend_Validate_Regex(
        array('pattern' => '/1234*/','pattern'=> '/4534*/')
);
```

I tryed also with Zend InArray validator, but I need to set different patterns, not a specifical string. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Do you need OR condition?

Comment: yes, I have 5-6 differente patterns, and I need the card respect one of theese

Comment: you can use `1234*|4534*`..`|` are alternation

Comment: Thanks to all ^__^

Comment: @BebPratzaBallus: Do you really want to match `12344444` like values? Because that is what your regex is doing. Maybe you need `1234.*`? To match `1234/any_text_here`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use meta-character `|`

```
'pattern' => '/1234*|4534*/'
```

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php